# Ubuntu Server 16.04 log message

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, users

I've recently started running check_mk (few days) to monitor my network and servers and started receiving critical service errors for service `user@1002`. When I take a look at the logs on the server, this is all I can find. The date listed below is when it first started appearing. I didn't notice it until check_mk notified me about it. I don't know what's causing it. I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04.3. The server seems to be functioning fine, but syslog is filled with this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of username.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Started Session c23158 of user username.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1002...
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Paths.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Timers.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Sockets.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Basic System.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Default.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Startup finished in 17ms.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1002.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1002...
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Stopped target Default.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Stopped target Timers.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Stopped target Paths.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[2795]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 2803 (kill).
Jun  2 06:26:15 host systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1002.
```

`journalctl -p debug -b` Output:

```
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host su[28998]: Successful su for username by root
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host su[28998]: + ??? root:username
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host su[28998]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of username.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd-logind[1421]: New session c3016 of user username.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Started Session c3016 of user username.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1002...
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Sockets.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Paths.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Timers.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Basic System.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Default.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Startup finished in 17ms.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1002.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host su[28998]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user username
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd-logind[1421]: Removed session c3016.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1002...
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Stopped target Default.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Stopped target Basic System.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Stopped target Timers.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Stopped target Paths.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Stopped target Sockets.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Reached target Shutdown.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Starting Exit the Session...
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29005]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 29022 (kill).
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[29009]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user username
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1002.
    Jun 09 16:21:15 host systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of username.
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No, I did not. I eventually set check_mk to ignore the error.